# Spring scan packages conflict between modules

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a multi module spring project where I have

- Parent pom

  - `persistence-module` (dev.company.persistence)
  - `rest-module` (dev.company.rest)
  - `notification-module` (dev.company.notification)

The `rest-module` has a dependency of `persistence-module` on pom.xml because I need to use a persistence classes.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

In `rest-module` I have a SpringBootApplication with @ComponentScan to find Repository Bean

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dev.company.persistence"})
@SpringBootApplication
```

But from the moment that I add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dev.company.persistence"})` I can't find beans on my `rest-module` like `@Controller` located in (`dev.company.rest.controller`) for example and HTTP calls give me always a 404 status.

I am printing the beans on `rest-module` and the classes are not loaded but @SpringBootApplication should scan automatically packages inside of `dev.company.rest` right ?

Seems me that exist a conflict when add `@ComponentScan` because its discovers the beans of the external module but the beans thenselves fail to recognise.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you add your own `@ComponentScan` annotation, it overrides the default one provided by `@SpringBootApplication` which searches in the current package. What stops you from adding the REST-package to the same `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Comment: If I add `dev.company.rest`as well to my actual `@ComponentScan` the application give me an error that can't find a `dev.company.persistence.repository` bean.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dev.company.persistence", "dev.company.rest"})
@SpringBootApplication

Comment: That's probably because you don't only need `@ComponentScan`, but also `@EntityScan` to scan the proper entities. The easiest is to use the `scanBasePackages` property of `@SpringBootApplication` and don't use `@ComponentScan` at all.

Comment: Strange because even with scanBasePackages like this 
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"`dev.company.rest`", "`dev.company.persistence`"}) does not work because the application said that a beans with type `dev.company.persistence.repository` is needed. But If I only add `dev.company.persistence` find the bean but of course not loaded properly the controller and can't access it from URL request.

Comment: I needed to add @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "dev.company.persistence.repository") on my dev.company.rest SpringBootApplication and works.